# Change of Variables and independent random variables.

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions, integration

Suppose that we have two IID random variables, $X_1, X_2$, carried by a triple $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$.

While solving an exercise I ended to a point that I had to see that,

$$
\iint\limits_D x_1 P_X(\mathrm dx_1)P_X(\mathrm dx_2) = \iint\limits_D x_2 P_X(\mathrm dx_2)P_X(\mathrm dx_1),
$$
where $D= \{ (x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x_1 + x_2 = c \} $ and  $ P_X$ is the law of $X_1, X_2$, i.e. the measure induced by $P$

The only way that I could identify it was by a change of variables.

Anyone can give me some intuition about this equality? Anyone can tell me something more simple than change of variables?

Comment: Identically distributed means $P_{X_1} = P_{X_2}$!!! The only difference is the dummy variable name: $x_1$ or $x_2$!!

Comment: Hint: $\int f(a,b) da db = \int f(x,y) dx dy$.

Comment: Thank you, I see your point.

Comment: You are welcome. It was a bit easy... but don't feel intimidated. Keep working!

Answer (score 2):

Both sides are $\displaystyle\iint_D u P_X(\mathrm du)P_X(\mathrm dv)$, or $\displaystyle\iint_D s P_X(\mathrm ds)P_X(\mathrm dt)$, or...